# How to get rid of numpy "bands" containing zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering

I have a 3D numpy array that represents 2D images at a given number of timesteps. The axes are organised as follows: (timestep, x_dimension, y_dimension). I would like to go through the timesteps and remove the "bands" that contain only zero values. I have a working solution that loops through the array but would like to implement a more pythonic approach. However, I am getting confused with the dimensions and can't see to apply a solution to an axis.
My current approach with a loop:

```
print(arr.shape)

> (20, 512, 512)
```

I have a 512x512 pixel image with 20 bands.

```
indices_zeros = []
# Loop through the first axis and find index of bands containing only zeros
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    if not arr[i, :, :].any():
        indices_zeros.append(i)

# Remove 0-axis elements based on previous step
new_array = np.delete(arr, indices_zeros, axis=0)
new_array.shape

> (7, 512, 512)
```

I would welcome any help in applying this approach without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the axis keyword for `all`:

```
indices_zeros = (arr == 0).all((1, 2))
new_array = arr[~indices_zero]
```